# What is the meaning of "reflection about"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

A book on algebra by Sullivian contains a sentence like this:

> Symmetry with respect to the
>   origin may be viewed as a reflection about the y-axis, followed by a reflection about the x-axis.

Here,what does the phrase "reflection about" means? is it equal to the phrase "reflection on"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, *about* takes the following meaning listed at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about):

> *around the outside*

In this context, the sentence refers to a reflection of what is on one side of an axis, to the opposite side, or "outside" of the axis.

This could also be described as a reflection *[around](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around)* an axis:

> *in or to an opposite direction or position*

Also, *[across](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/across)* an axis:

> from one side to the opposite side of

To describe a reflection as being *on* an axis would be less clear than either of the above terms, as it could also indicate a reflection of the content found on one side of an axis back onto that *same* side.

However, a reflection *in* an axis would work, in the same way that a reflection *in* a mirror refers to a (conceptual) "other side" across the plane of reflection.

A useful example of the overall meaning from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) reads:

> *... the mirror image of the small Latin letter p for a reflection with respect to a vertical axis would look like q. Its image by reflection in a horizontal axis would look like b.*